# IO/Pty error when compiling PERL script

Tags: perl

It has been awhile since I have done any PERL programming and I am working on a project where I need to connect to a remote server and get a listing of files.  The script is being developed on a Windows 2012 server using ActivePerl.

This is the script that I have put together, from other examples -

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use autodie;

use Net::SFTP::Foreign;

# US Server Configuration
use constant {
    HOST            => "samplehost",
    REMOTE_DIR      => "sample/remote",
    LOCAL_DIR       => "sample/local",
    PORT            => "3235",
    USER_NAME       => "username",
    PASSWORD        => "D%password",
    DEBUG           => "0",
};

my $stfp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new (
    HOST,
    timeout         => 240,
    user            => USER_NAME,
    password        => PASSWORD,
    port            => PORT,
    autodie         => 1,
);

#
# List remote directory contents
#
my $remotefiles;
$remotefiles = $stfp->ls(REMOTE_DIR); 

#
# Loop through remote files and print each filename
#
foreach ($remotefiles){
    my $file = $_;
    my $filename = $file->{filename};
    if($filename ne "." && $filename ne ".."){
        print"the filename is $filename";
    }
}
```

I am receiving an error when I compile it -

```
C:\development>perl ConvertPDFs.pl
password authentication not available, IO::Pty is not installed or failed to loa
d: Can't locate IO/Pty.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Perl64/site/lib C:/Perl64/l
ib .) at C:/Perl64/site/lib/Net/SFTP/Foreign/Backend/Unix.pm line 256.
 at ConvertPDFs.pl line 20.
```

Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: The problem is: `IO::Pty` is not installed or failed to load....

Comment: How do I install that package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo-ttys are a unix construct. If a module requires IO::Pty, it won't run on Windows (though maybe on cygwin). On the plus side, the error message makes it sound like Net::SFTP::Foreign only uses IO::Pty for password-based authentication, so you could avoid the problem by switching to key-based authentication.